# Rails nested resource on a singular resource form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm having a problem with Rails not POSTing anything in the params to an action.
I'm using a singular resource with a nested plural resource which may or may
not be where the problem is coming from (Rails has issues with form_for and singular
resource URLs).

Anyway, I have this in my routes:

```
resource :event do
    resources :actions, :only => [:create], :controller => "events/actions"
end
```

The view:

```
<%= form_for([@event, Action.new], :remote => true) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :team_id %>
    <br />
    <%= f.text_field :team_id %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :message %>
    <br />
    <%= f.text_field :message %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :score %>
    <br />
    <%= f.number_field :score %>
  </div>
  <br />
  <%= f.submit "Update score" %> or <%= link_to "cancel", "#", :id => "cancel" %>
<% end %>
```

The create action:

```
def create
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @action = @event.actions.create(params[:action])
end
```

Ok pretty standard no worries there.
But when I get the params from Rails nothing is there. :(

Params:

```
Started POST "/event/actions.4e67f09349ae71090c00000e"
Processing by Events::ActionsController#create as
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"Γ£ô", "authenticity_token"=>"stuff", "commit"=>"Update score"}

Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 31ms
```

What is going on here?

**Edit:**

If I remove the ":remote => true" line in my view,
I see that in my params I get one param ":format"
which appears to be the ID of the event.

However, I'm still not getting the action params. :(

Comment: remove the remote and look at the logs

Comment: I did that and I see a format param (instead of event_id) with an id getting passed. But I still see no params for the action? I don't get it.

Comment: please update your question with these extra info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally I'd like to see those event & action models - I suspect that's where the problem lies. Without seeing those, a few suggestions:

- Is 'accepts_nested_attributes_for :action' set in the event model?
- Remove any 'attr_accessible' line from both models & see if things work. (Keep in mind you need to set accessible attributes for nested forms in the parent model)
- 'Action' seems like an imprudent name for a model. It's possible rails is overwriting 'action' methods with things related to the actual action

Hope this helps - I'd suggest posting the models if you still can't find a solution.

Comment: You are right. Since Rails uses params[:action] for the actual action (not the model) my model was messing everything up. I've renamed it and it works just fine now. Thanks!